# Is there a Hadith which says “Whoever insults a prophet, kill him”?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, blasphemy

I can’t remember it clearly so my wording may be inaccurate.  I recall it being attributed to the musannaf Ibn Abi shaybah, but I could be wrong about that as well.

sorry, I know this isn’t much to go on...

is there such a Hadith?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there exists a hadith with this wording. It is narrated by Ali ibn Abi Talib from the Prophet  ﷺ; and is recorded in [Al-Shifaa bi Tareef Huqooq al-Mustafaa](https://shamela.ws/book/1753/604) and [Mu'jam al-Sagheer Tabaraani](https://www.shamela.ws/index.php/book/13068/766) etc.

> #### مَنْ سَبَّ نَبِيًّا فَاقْتُلُوهُ

The scholars have noted that the chain for this hadith has some weakness, however the content is accepted to be correct. The same meaning is conveyed by several other ahadith such as on the execution of [Ka'b bin Al-Ashraf](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4037) or [Abu Rafi'](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4039) or [Ibn Khatal](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4286) or the [slave woman](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/11) of the blind sahabi etc. And it is corroborated by the verdicts of the caliphs and the sayings of the sahaba.

> وأجمعوا على أن من سب النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم أن له القتل
>
> They are unanimous that whoever insults the Prophet ﷺ is to be killed
>
> <sup>— [Al-Ijma' - Ibn Mundhir](https://shamela.ws/book/12445/139)</sup>

> من سب نبيا من الأنبياء قتل باتفاق الفقهاء
>
> Whoever insults a prophet from the prophets, is to be killed, by the agreement of the jurists
>
> <sup>— [Majmoo‘ al-Fataawa](https://shamela.ws/book/7289/4870)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Shaykh Albani deemed this narration to be fabricated in Silsilah ad-Da'ifah (1/372 - #[206](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/403)) because of the narrator Al-U'mri, who is accused by Al-Hafiz Ibn Hajar and An-Nasa'i of lying and fabricating ahadith.

Comment: At least in the version of al-Qadi 'Iyad in his a-Shifa' this narrator doesn't appear.